# Browser suddenly stops working occasionally; other internet services keep working

Tags: router, troubleshooting

The problem is that about 50% of the time whenever I try to use Firefox to browse the internet the page doesn't load and eventually times out. The other half of the time, it works perfectly and quickly.

While Firefox isn't working, the computer doesn't report my internet as having been lost. Skype still works without any issues. Torrenting does not (it acts as if my internet is out completely.)

The problem started when I moved my computer to a different house and different internet connection. It's connected through a router, but the other computers that are connected both wired and wirelessly don't have issues, ever.

I've tried swapping out ethernet cables, reboots, proxy settings, all that.

The computer worked perfectly on the old connection.

And this connection, and the router, works perfectly.

So what could the issue be?

Update: I want to be explicit about one more thing; when Firefox is not working, that's for some period of time, say 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

go to a command prompt and type in ping www.google.com -t ( you can also try several other large famous websites ). Let it run for a bit and then hit cntrl+c to cancel the ping. It will report the % of packet loss. If you have high packet loss this could cause the weird browser problem.

If other devices connected to the router on different ports never have issues, perhaps a port on your router is damaged?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Swapping ports didn't do anything. As for packet loss, the request always times out during periods of my browser not working, and there's no packet loss when it is working.